# Japanese characters won't appear when printed

Tags: python, unicode

I am printing Unicode characters in python. All of the symbols I have used so far work except for Japanese characters. When I print the characters, it only shows the "question mark in a box" symbol. How can I fix this?

When I first countered the problem I thought it might be python. I searched Google, but I found almost nothing.
Then I wondered if it was Command Prompt. (I use Command Prompt to test my code.) No relevant results.
For my code, I use a list made of the Unicode characters so I won't have to look up and type the specific code. This is what it looks like.

```
UD = [u"\u3053", u"\u3093", u"\u306B", u"\u3061", u"\u306F"]
UDTemp = UD[0] + UD[1] + UD[2] + UD[3] + UD[4]
print(UDTemp)
```

When printing, I expected "こんにちは", but instead I got the weird symbols.

Comment: you sure the font you use to display that text features these characters? also `weird symbols` means what exactly?

Comment: I never thought of that, I'll look into it. Also, by "weird symbols", I mean the "question marks in squares" thing I was talking about earlier.

Answer (score 2):

The font has to support the characters.  For example, I have east Asia IMEs installed on a US Windows 10 system, which make available fonts that support Japanese:

[image: Console image showing Command Prompt Properties page and visible Japanese characters]

To obtain the fonts you want, it is easiest to add the language support for the desired language in Window 10.  To add a language, search for "Language settings":

[image: Language settings window]

Once the language is installed, fonts supporting that language will appear in the Console properties, and IMEs will be installed so you can type in that language if you know how to use them.

Comment: I brought up the Command Prompt properties, but the only 2 fonts I have on there don't support it. I looked up a tutorial on how to add new ones to the Command Prompt, but I ran into a problem. It says to go to a certain path in the Registry Editor, but I can't find the path. Am I doing this right?

Comment: @Thatonegamer59 It's easier to just install the language you want support for.  That should add the fonts for you.  Assuming Windows 10, go to Region & Language settings and and the language you want support for.